# How do I set owner and group on git files on checkout from hooks/post-receive?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm maintaining several websites using Git after following this guide http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

I make changes to my local repository and commit
I then git push to a remote repository on my server
In hooks/post-receive I do this:

```
#! /bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/user/public_html/ git checkout -f
```

This works very well except I push via ssh as root so all checked out files are owned by root:root.  This causes permission problems.

The solution I'm currently using is to add a line to the post-receive file like:

```
chown -R user:user /home/user/public_html/*
```

This works fine, apart from the obvious problem of setting ALL files in public_html to user:user which isn't necessarily what is want and is probably a bit inefficient.  Also it introduces another chance to type user:user wrong.

So:

1. Is there a way to only set the files that are being checked out rather than all the files in public_html?
2. Is there a way to stop the files being owned by root:root in the first place?  I have to ssh in as root as I don't want to give other users ssh access.

Comment: You don't want to give other users ssh access, but you give root privileges ? oO

Comment: Nope only I have root privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think pushing files to `git` as `root` system user matters. Because `git` does not necessarily use `system user` as `git user`.

There is something incorrect about your deployment workflow.

Instead of checking out the files directly into `public_html`, you should probably use another folder, which is not in the `DocumentRoot`. Exposing your `git repo` to the world may not be what you want to do.

I suggest you have another folder `/home/user/git_cache`

```
cd /home/user/git_cache && git checkout -f
cp -RpP /home/user/git_cache/* /home/user/public_html/*
```

Comment: The git repo is outside of public_html, this is why I checkout to public_html after a push. See the link in my question

Comment: There must be a reason why the files are owned by root after this - maybe it's because the repo is owned by root? I'll test this

Comment: Tried it, doesn't matter who is the owner and group of the repo, the files checked out to public_html are owned by root:root.

Comment: Try prepending the git checkout command with sudo -u like this 'sudo -u user git checkout'

Comment: Tried this and I get 'sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo'

Comment: use `gitosis` or `gitolite` to simplify permission handling. Even better if you could switch to `capistrano`(simple) or `chef`, `puppet` (complex), for managing your deployments. To continue with your current approach take a [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9573247/1243123)

Comment: Thanks you've been most helpful

Comment: This gave me the idea I needed to script something more comprehensive, including taking a pre-copy backup of production. Thank you very much.